# how to make switch and case work?

Tags: android, switch-statement, case

I have a game project for Android that have source code like this :

```
package com.example.fun;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;



public class DogActivity extends Activity {
      Button buttonA;
      Button buttonB;
      Button buttonC;
      Button buttonD;
      Button buttonE;
      Button buttonF;
      Button buttonG;
      Button buttonH;
      Button buttonI;
      Button buttonJ;
      Button buttonK;
      Button buttonL;
      Button buttonM;
      Button buttonN;
      Button buttonO;
      Button buttonP;
      Button buttonQ;
      Button buttonR;
      Button buttonS;
      Button buttonT;
      Button buttonU;
      Button buttonV;
      Button buttonX;
      Button buttonW;
      Button buttonY;
      Button buttonZ;
      Button next;
      Intent i;
      TextView txtD;
      TextView txtO;
      TextView txtG;
      int life=3;
      TextView nyaw;
      TextView nyaw2;
      TextView nyaw3;
      TextView kesempatan;
      boolean l1,l2,l3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dog);
        buttonA = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAbout);
        buttonB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonhelp);
        buttonC = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonc);
        buttonD = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttond);
        buttonE = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonE);
        buttonF = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonf);
        buttonG = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttong);
        buttonH = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonh);
        buttonI = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttoni);
        buttonJ = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonj);
        buttonK = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonk);
        buttonL = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonl);
        buttonM = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonm);
        buttonN = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonn);
        buttonO = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttono);
        buttonP = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonp);
        buttonQ = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonq);
        buttonR = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonr);
        buttonS = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttons);
        buttonT = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttont);
        buttonU = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonu);
        buttonV = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonv);
        buttonW = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonw);
        buttonX = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonx);
        buttonY = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttony);
        buttonZ = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonz);
        next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);
        txtD = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewD);
        txtO = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewO);
        txtG = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewG);
        nyaw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nyawa);
        nyaw2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nyawa2);
        nyaw3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nyawa3);
        buttonA.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonB.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonC.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonD.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonE.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonF.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonG.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonH.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonI.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonJ.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonK.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonL.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonM.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonN.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonO.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonP.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonQ.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonR.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonS.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonT.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonU.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonV.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonW.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonX.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonY.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        buttonZ.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
        next.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    }
    View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {
              if( buttonD.getId() == ((Button)v).getId() ){
                  txtD.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }
              else if( buttonO.getId() == ((Button)v).getId() ){
                  txtO.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }
              else if( buttonG.getId() == ((Button)v).getId() ){
                  txtG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  i = new Intent(DogActivity.this, HouseActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);   
              }
              else if( next.getId() == ((Button)v).getId() ){
                  i = new Intent(DogActivity.this, HouseActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);   
              }
              else{
                  MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.no);
                    mp.start();
                  life--;   
                    **switch (life) {
                    case 2:
                        nyaw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                    case 1:
                        nyaw2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                    case 0:
                        nyaw3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        i = new Intent(DogActivity.this, TamatActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    break;
                }**
              }

          }

};

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dog, menu);
        return false;
    }

}
```

But when I run it, the switch and case code was didn't work. Am I put it in the wrong place or the code is wrong? Thanks for the answer..

Comment: After `life--` Log the value of life and check whether it matches with any case

Comment: Try adding debug statements to each of your if/else clauses and to the switch cases to see if your code gets executed or not. You can do debug with Log.d("TAG", "Message"); Try and print something useful in the message part, eg. the name of the button or the number of the case. This will then show up in your LogCat console.

Comment: @Daniel.  Logcat is not for debugging (in general).  As the name suggests, it's for logging.  Please don't carry on this disease in the Android community where people don't learn to use the `debugger`, which is the correct way to find issues like this.  If everyone used the debugger, 90% of questions on StackOverflow would be unnecessary.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?  It tells us nothing.

Comment: @Simon I mean that the text view still visible so the command was didn't work.

Comment: @nichi that means your case statements are not executed. So log `life` after `life--` and see if it matches any of the case.

Comment: @Raghunandan can you give me example how to log `life` after `life--`?
sorry,but I'm still new on android programming, so I don't get it clearly. Thanks..

Comment: @nichi `Log.i("Current Life Value is",""+life)` and check the value in logcat. also check this http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check following answer for your requirement.

This will work properly and i just have changed few 
sentances nothing else.

See below.

```
View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {
          if( R.id.buttond == ((Button)v).getId() ){
              txtD.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
          else if( buttonO.getId() == ((Button)v).getId() ){
              txtO.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
          else if( R.id.buttono == ((Button)v).getId() ){
              txtG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              i = new Intent(DogActivity.this, HouseActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);   
          }
          else if( R.id.buttonnext == ((Button)v).getId() ){
              i = new Intent(DogActivity.this, HouseActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);   
          }
          else{
              MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.no);
                mp.start();
              life--;   
                **switch (life) {
                case 2:
                    nyaw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
                case 1:
                    nyaw2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
                case 0:
                    nyaw3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    i = new Intent(DogActivity.this, TamatActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                break;
            }**
          }

      }
  //You can also use switch case for this.
};
```